# DQL Jsor/doctrine-postgis

Tags: symfony, doctrine, postgis, dql

I'm triying to get a calculated value from database where this value depends on an external value. I got the next function:

```
public function findAllBy($search, $order, $limit, $offset) {
    $qb = $this->entityManager
               ->createQueryBuilder()
               ->select('a, (ST_DISTANCE(ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(0,0)) / 1000) as distance')
               ->from('App\Entity\App\Advertisement', 'a')
               ->setMaxResult($limit)
               ->setFirstResult($offset);

    for ($order as $key => $value)
        $qb->andWhere($key !== "distance" ? "a.{$key}" : "distance", $value);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This function works, but the problem comes now. Like I said, I need to modify two parameters, one of theme come from outside of this function, that's not a problem, the problem comes with the other one. I the advertisement table I got a column named "coordinate" of type Point (postgis), when I try to substitute one of ST_MakePoint like this:

```
(ST_DISTANCE(ST_MakePoint(a.coordinate[0] a.coordinate[1]), ST_MakePoint(0,0)) / 1000) as distance
```

I got the next error:

```
"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 49: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_COMMA, got '['"
```

I also tried:

```
(ST_DISTANCE(a.coordinate::geometry, ST_MakePoint(0,0)) / 1000) as distance
"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 35: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_COMMA, got ':'"
```

Other:

```
ERROR:  function st_distance(point, geometry) does not exist
(ST_DISTANCE(a.coordinate, ST_MakePoint(0,0)) / 1000) as distance // Error coordinate not a geometry
```

Other:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 54: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ':'"
(ST_DISTANCE(a.coordinate, ST_MakePoint(0,0)::point) / 1000) as distance
```

None of them works. I dont how can I use the coordinate column on DQL.
If that helps, I got another function that works, but it is SQL not DQL, and I dont know how to parse the result as entity. Here it is:

```
SELECT x.id
FROM (
    SELECT
        g.id,
        (ST_DISTANCE(ST_MakePoint(g.coordinate[0], g.coordinate[1])::geography, ST_MakePoint($point)::geography) / 1000) as distance
    FROM app.graveyard g
    ) AS x
WHERE x.distance <= 100
ORDER BY x.distance ASC
```

[image]

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\App;

use App\DBAL\Types\Geolocation\Point;
use App\Repository\App\AdvertisementRepository;
use App\Tools\Tools;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AdvertisementRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(schema="app")
 */
class Advertisement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=App\Entity\App\Company::class, inversedBy="advertisements")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="AdvertisementTypeEnum")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $nicheTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=App\Entity\App\AdvertisementComplement::class, mappedBy="advertisement")
     */
    private $advertisementComplements;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=App\Entity\App\AdvertisementTransfer::class, mappedBy="advertisement")
     */
    private $advertisementTransfers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=App\Entity\App\AdvertisementGraveyard::class, mappedBy="advertisement")
     */
    private $advertisementGraveyards;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=App\Entity\App\AdvertisementFuneralParlor::class, mappedBy="advertisement")
     */
    private $advertisementFuneralParlors;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AdvertisementCrematorium::class, mappedBy="advertisement")
     */
    private $advertisementCrematoria;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $query;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AdvertisementStatistic::class, mappedBy="advertisement")
     */
    private $advertisementStatistics;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $publishDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AdvertisementRate::class, mappedBy="advertisement")
     */
    private $advertisementRates;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default":10000})
     */
    private $version;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Contract::class, mappedBy="advertisement", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
     */
    private $contracts;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $wake;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $wakeTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $wakePrice;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $kmExtraPrice;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $wakeIncluded;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=City::class)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="point", nullable=true)
     */
    private $coordinate;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->advertisementComplements = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->advertisementTransfers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->advertisementGraveyards = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->advertisementFuneralParlors = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->advertisementCrematoria = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->createAt = new \DateTime("now");
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime("now");
        $this->advertisementStatistics = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->advertisementRates = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->contracts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->coordinate = $this->city->getCoordinate();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCompany(): ?Company
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function setCompany(?Company $company): self
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType($type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNicheTime(): ?int
    {
        return $this->nicheTime;
    }

    public function setNicheTime(?int $nicheTime): self
    {
        $this->nicheTime = $nicheTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnabled(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    public function setEnabled(bool $enabled): self
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdvertisementComplement[]|null
     */
    public function getAdvertisementComplements(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->advertisementComplements;
    }

    public function addAdvertisementComplement(AdvertisementComplement $advertisementComplement): self
    {
        if (!$this->advertisementComplements->contains($advertisementComplement)) {
            $this->advertisementComplements[] = $advertisementComplement;
            $advertisementComplement->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdvertisementComplement(AdvertisementComplement $advertisementComplement): self
    {
        if ($this->advertisementComplements->removeElement($advertisementComplement)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($advertisementComplement->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $advertisementComplement->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdvertisementTransfer[]|null
     */
    public function getAdvertisementTransfers(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->advertisementTransfers;
    }

    public function addAdvertisementTransfer(AdvertisementTransfer $advertisementTransfer): self
    {
        if (!$this->advertisementTransfers->contains($advertisementTransfer)) {
            $this->advertisementTransfers[] = $advertisementTransfer;
            $advertisementTransfer->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdvertisementTransfer(AdvertisementTransfer $advertisementTransfer): self
    {
        if ($this->advertisementTransfers->removeElement($advertisementTransfer)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($advertisementTransfer->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $advertisementTransfer->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdvertisementGraveyard[]
     */
    public function getAdvertisementGraveyards(): Collection
    {
        return $this->advertisementGraveyards;
    }

    public function addAdvertisementGraveyard(AdvertisementGraveyard $advertisementGraveyard): self
    {
        if (!$this->advertisementGraveyards->contains($advertisementGraveyard)) {
            $this->advertisementGraveyards[] = $advertisementGraveyard;
            $advertisementGraveyard->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdvertisementGraveyard(AdvertisementGraveyard $advertisementGraveyard): self
    {
        if ($this->advertisementGraveyards->removeElement($advertisementGraveyard)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($advertisementGraveyard->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $advertisementGraveyard->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdvertisementFuneralParlor[]
     */
    public function getAdvertisementFuneralParlors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->advertisementFuneralParlors;
    }

    public function addAdvertisementFuneralParlor(AdvertisementFuneralParlor $advertisementFuneralParlor): self
    {
        if (!$this->advertisementFuneralParlors->contains($advertisementFuneralParlor)) {
            $this->advertisementFuneralParlors[] = $advertisementFuneralParlor;
            $advertisementFuneralParlor->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdvertisementFuneralParlor(AdvertisementFuneralParlor $advertisementFuneralParlor): self
    {
        if ($this->advertisementFuneralParlors->removeElement($advertisementFuneralParlor)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($advertisementFuneralParlor->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $advertisementFuneralParlor->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuery(): ?int
    {
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function setQuery(int $query): self
    {
        $this->query = $query;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdvertisementCrematorium[]
     */
    public function getAdvertisementCrematoria(): Collection
    {
        return $this->advertisementCrematoria;
    }

    public function addAdvertisementCrematorium(AdvertisementCrematorium $advertisementCrematorium): self
    {
        if (!$this->advertisementCrematoria->contains($advertisementCrematorium)) {
            $this->advertisementCrematoria[] = $advertisementCrematorium;
            $advertisementCrematorium->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdvertisementCrematorium(AdvertisementCrematorium $advertisementCrematorium): self
    {
        if ($this->advertisementCrematoria->removeElement($advertisementCrematorium)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($advertisementCrematorium->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $advertisementCrematorium->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreateAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createAt;
    }

    public function getCreateAtNormalized(): string
    {
        return $this->createAt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    public function setCreateAt(): self
    {
        $this->createAt = new \DateTime("now");

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function getUpdateAtNormalized(): string
    {
        return $this->updatedAt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime("now");

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdvertisementStatistic[]
     */
    public function getAdvertisementStatistics(): Collection
    {
        return $this->advertisementStatistics;
    }

    public function addAdvertisementStatistic(AdvertisementStatistic $advertisementStatistic): self
    {
        if (!$this->advertisementStatistics->contains($advertisementStatistic)) {
            $this->advertisementStatistics[] = $advertisementStatistic;
            $advertisementStatistic->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdvertisementStatistic(AdvertisementStatistic $advertisementStatistic): self
    {
        if ($this->advertisementStatistics->removeElement($advertisementStatistic)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($advertisementStatistic->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $advertisementStatistic->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublishDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publishDate;
    }

    public function setPublishDate(): self
    {
        $this->publishDate = new \DateTime("now");
        return $this;
    }

    public function clearPublishDate(): self
    {
        $this->publishDate = null;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdvertisementRate[]
     */
    public function getAdvertisementRates(): Collection
    {
        return $this->advertisementRates;
    }

    public function addAdvertisementRate(AdvertisementRate $advertisementRate): self
    {
        if (!$this->advertisementRates->contains($advertisementRate)) {
            $this->advertisementRates[] = $advertisementRate;
            $advertisementRate->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdvertisementRate(AdvertisementRate $advertisementRate): self
    {
        if ($this->advertisementRates->removeElement($advertisementRate)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($advertisementRate->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $advertisementRate->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVersion(): int
    {
        return $this->version;
    }

    public function getStringVersion(): string
    {
        $v = $this->getVersion();
        $result = "";

        while ($v > 0) {
            $result = ((strlen($result) + 2) % 3) == 0 ? '.' . $v %10 . $result : $v %10 . $result;
            $v = (int)($v / 10);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function setVersion(int $version): self
    {
        $this->version = $version;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Contract[]
     */
    public function getContracts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->contracts;
    }

    public function addContract(Contract $contract): self
    {
        if (!$this->contracts->contains($contract)) {
            $this->contracts[] = $contract;
            $contract->setAdvertisement($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeContract(Contract $contract): self
    {
        if ($this->contracts->removeElement($contract)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($contract->getAdvertisement() === $this) {
                $contract->setAdvertisement(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWake(): bool
    {
        return $this->wake;
    }

    public function setWake(bool $wake): self
    {
        $this->wake = $wake;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWakeTime(): ?int
    {
        return $this->wakeTime;
    }

    public function setWakeTime(?int $wakeTime): self
    {
        $this->wakeTime = $wakeTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWakePrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->wakePrice;
    }

    public function setWakePrice(?float $wakePrice): self
    {
        $this->wakePrice = $wakePrice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getKmExtraPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->kmExtraPrice;
    }

    public function setKmExtraPrice(?float $kmExtraPrice): self
    {
        $this->kmExtraPrice = $kmExtraPrice;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWakeIncluded(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->wakeIncluded;
    }

    private function getJsonRates(): array
    {
        $size = sizeof($this->advertisementRates);
        if ($size == 0) return [];
        $average = 0.0;
        $jsonRates = [];
        foreach ($this->advertisementRates as $advertisementRate) {
            array_push($jsonRates, $advertisementRate->toJsonArray());
            $average += $advertisementRate->getScore();
        }

        $average /= $size;
        return ["average" => $average, "rates" => $jsonRates, "size" => $size];
    }

    public function getDeletedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $deletedAt): self
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setWakeIncluded(?bool $wakeIncluded): self
    {
        $this->wakeIncluded = $wakeIncluded;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?City
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(?City $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDistance(Point $destiny)
    {
        dump($this->tools);
        return 0;
//        return $this->tools->getDistanceBetweenPoint($this->coordinate, $destiny);
    }

    public function toJsonArray(): array
    {
        $publishDate = $this->getPublishDate();
        $rates = $this->getJsonRates();

        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "companyId" => $this->company->getId(),
            "name" => $this->name,
            "description" => $this->description,
            "type" => $this->type,
            "basePrice" => $this->price,
            "query" => $this->query,
            "updateAt" => $this->getUpdateAtNormalized(),
            "publishDate" => !is_null($publishDate) ? $publishDate->format("d-m-Y") : null,
            "enable" => $this->enabled,
            "version" => $this->getStringVersion(),
            "wake" => $this->wake,
            "wakeIncluded" => $this->wakeIncluded,
            "wakePrice" => $this->wakePrice,
            "wakeTime" => $this->wakeTime,
            "kmExtraPrice" => $this->kmExtraPrice,
            "rates" => empty($rates) ?
                null :
                [
                    "average" => $rates['average'],
                    "rates" => $rates['rates'],
                    "ratesCount" => $rates['size']
                ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: `ST_MakePoint(a.coordinate[0] a.coordinate[1])` there is literally a comma missing. `g.coordinate[0]` will not work because DQL can only handle direct property values, so if `coordinate` is an array, you have to map it differently. It would help if you could add mapping of all properties used inside the DQL. How is anyone supposed to know what DQL needs without the property mapping?

Comment: I already added in the post.

Comment: Where? I only see the SQL column types, not where or how they are mapped to your entity...

Comment: Column-Type `type="point"` is not Standard-Doctrine but an extension, usually it will give you an object of a `Point`-class that might have properties like `$x`/`$y` etc. AND you MIGHT be able to use these properties in DQL `g.coordinate.x`/ `g.coordinate.y`. I am NOT sure if that works BUT you definitely can only work with mapped Object-properties in DQL AND with limitations e.g. you can NOT access array indexes in DQL when a property is mapped as an array (at least i wouldn't know that this works, but still try it anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I will try as soon as posible I can. I comment when I done with it.

Comment: I try and get this error:
**"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 49 near 'latitude, a.coordinate.longitude),': Error: Class App\\Entity\\App\\Advertisement has no field or association named coordinate.latitude",**

Comment: Again, all properties must be properly mapped with Doctrine AND there is NO property `$latitude` in the `Advertisement` Entity. How do think this stuff works?

Comment: Sry, I got a bad day and I donw see it properly. How can I map the '$latitude' and '$longitude' from another entity on this one, without create it as graveyard property

Comment: You don't, properties from another entity can be accessed by joining the entity `JOIN a.<property> <alias>` BUT `$coordinate` does NOT seem to be another entity but a custom type, and for custom types the properties can be accessed directly (to my knowledge).